# Is Apache RewriteRule interfering with If and Location directives?

Tags: regex, laravel, apache, .htaccess, shibboleth

I'm using Apache to implement Shibboleth single sign on for a Laravel site. I'd like to bypass one specific subset of URLs from authentication (`api/public`, for example) so they're publicly accessible. For some reason the public folder's `.htaccess` file seems to be preventing this from working as expected.

I've tried this a bunch of different ways and all roads have lead to this same issue. Here's what I'm trying currently.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/public>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#api/public#">
        Require all granted
    </If>
    <Else>
        AuthType shibboleth
        ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
        Require valid-user
    </Else>
</Directory>
```

Here's the `.htaccess` file that Laravel ships with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately with the `.htaccess` file in place, the `Else` code is still getting executed and the Shib code runs. But I'm pretty sure the `If` condition is catching, because if throw in `Require all denied` as a test then it does forbid as expected.

If I remove the `.htaccess` however, this works! But it also means that any routing within Laravel is now broken, which I do need for this public-facing URL.

My best guess is that the `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` is causing the `Else` code to still run even after the `If` statement caught. Any suggestions on a way around this? Running into the same problem using `Location` directive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution for this, will share here in case someone else runs into this. The issue was indeed that `RewriteRule` causes us to run through the whole thing again. The `If` stopped Shibboleth as expected the first time, but then we'd go through again after Laravel redirects us to `index.php` and pick it up anyway.

Solved it by changing the `Else` to an `ElseIf` where we exclude `index.php`:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/public>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#api/public#">
        Require all granted
    </If>
    <ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#index\.php#">
        AuthType shibboleth
        ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
        Require valid-user
    </ElseIf>
</Directory>
```